# With DBeaver, MariaDB Optimizer Trace a result irrelevant to the concerned query

Tags: mariadb, dbeaver

With a non-root user on 10.5.18-MariaDB, we are trying to get the optimizer trace about the SQL query `select * from eav_value ev`; however, the result seems to be irrelevant, saying something about `select database() AS DATABASE()`:

```
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "join_preparation": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "steps": [
          {
            "expanded_query": "select database() AS `DATABASE()`"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "join_optimization": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "steps": []
      }
    },
    {
      "join_execution": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "steps": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

We also tried to get the optimizer traces for other queries but got the same result as above, regardless of the query.

If change to use the CLI connection, the system behaviour is OK. We prefer the GUI tools, e.g. DBeaver, though.

We are learning how to use the optimizer trace, so we wonder if we missed anything.

**The commands used in the test:**

```sql
select @@version
;
show create table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OPTIMIZER_TRACE
;
set session OPTIMIZER_TRACE = "enabled=on"
;
select * from eav_value ev
;
select * from information_schema.OPTIMIZER_TRACE
;
set session OPTIMIZER_TRACE = "enabled=off"
;
```

Comment: Does putting it after a `start transaction` help? If the query is `create table x.saved_optimiser_t as select * from information_schema.optimizer_trace` does that preserve it for later?

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver uses [MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/). It looks like this driver disconnects after completing the query.

Therefore, when getting for the optimizer trace, it is not the same session as the query before. The optimizer trace depends on the session.

We are still open to suggestions about how to keep DBeaver hold on to the same session and not to disconnect after each query.